# Different payload in firebase notification between real device and simulator

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Flutter and I am experiencing a strange behavior when sending notification from the firebase cloud messaging console. If I send a notification to a real device, then the message I get is like this

```
on message {
  google.c.sender.id: 801xxxxx873, 
  google.c.a.e: 1, 
  aps: {
    alert: {title: Test 33, body: Test test 44}
  }, 
  gcm.n.e: 1, 
  google.c.a.c_id: 10xxxxxx18, 
  google.c.a.udt: 0,
  gcm.message_id: 1592xxxxxxxx6906, 
  google.c.a.ts: 159xxxxx07
}
```

If I do the same on the ios simulator I get the following

```
on message {
  from: 80xxxx873, 
  collapse_key: xxxxx.com.xxxx02, 
  notification: {
    body: Test test 44, title: Test 33, e: 1, tag: campaign_collapse_key_559xxxxxxx002
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why? I  believe the first case is in line with apple documentation while the  second one is the JSON structure I get when sending to Android

Is there a way to get the same JSON regardless if it is a real device or a simulator?
Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure but it might be because of google services is only running on real devices which adds that additional fields. or google might just dont want to store extra data for emulator/simulator devices.